# Format rails data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I have such integer values like yearmonth, but i wont to see month-year, how I can do this in rails view? 
for example

> 197903  198812

must be viewed as

> 03-1979 12-1988

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
"#{197903.to_s[0...4]}-#{197903.to_s[4...6]}"
```

There may be a more elegant way of doing this if you can convert it to a date object first.

Comment: you said you had an integer not a date.

Comment: one more question: is it better to concat strings in view (i'll will do in such way %td= link_to model.MOD_PCON_START.to_s[4...6].concat("-").concat(model.MOD_PCON_START.to_s[0...4]), model) or it' isbetter to do in controller, and send to view?

Comment: You should probably make it a helper method that you call from the view. The controller should stay free of view specific logic. also you don't need to do that concat at all because what I showed you is actually works the same way e.g. "#{model.MOD_PCON_START.to_s[0...4]}-#{model.MOD_PCON_START.to_s[4...6]}"